# Can't find node in Godot

Tags: button, sidebar, godot, mobile-application

I'm trying to create a simple sidebar that moves in and out when you click a button. There is a button with a script (which should be under the main scene, but was moved over to the sidebar scene for testing), and a sidebar node which, when called, will either move in or move out. The code should be right, but for some reason the node path cannot be found and thus called, causing an error. Would appreciate any advice to make this cleaner as well.

I have tried changing the path. I have tried creating a scene unique node. I have tried changing the scene that the code is under. I was expecting the sidebar to move when I clicked the button, but it just exited with an error that said "node not found".